# Hidden Values in Listview items?

Tags: c#

**Is There a way to add hidden values to a listview item?**

I am creating a listview where I show data from a database.
I also want to be able to edit this therefore I need two IDs to make sure it's the correct item and I don't mess up the database

Is there any way to do this?
I Tried adding an ID to the TAG property of the list view item.

```
   ListViewItem track = new ListViewItem();
            track.Tag = id;
            track.Text = ("Test: " + SL[i] + " Test: " + SL[i + 1]);
            listView1.Items.Add(track);
```

But I need to add 2 IDs to an item.

EDIT: I am using Winforms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary<int,int>` and and set it  to `Tag` and get it back by searching `ListViewItem`.

Add

```
   Dictionary<int, int> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        ListViewItem track = new ListViewItem();
        dictionary.Add(0, 21);
        dictionary.Add(1, 45);
        track.Tag = dictionary;
        track.Text = ("Test: 1" + " Test: 2");
        listView1.Items.Add(track);
```

Get

```
 var x = listView1.Items[0].Tag;
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways to solve this:

You can extend `ListViewItem` in a new class and add your two properties to that class.

You can create a Tuple that contains both IDs and store that in the `Tag`.

Answer (score 0):

Create class that contains 2 fields ID1 ID2:

```
public class Class1
{
    public int ID1 { get; set; }
    public int ID2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then while populating ListViewItems, assign Class1 object to Tag property

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();            
Class1 c1 = new Class1() { ID1 = 1,ID2 = 2 };            
item.Tag = c1;
listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

To get ID's from ListViewItem cast Tag property as Class1 :

```
Class1 c = (Class1)item.Tag;
MessageBox.Show(c.ID1.ToString());
```